# Change order of Flexbox elements list to read top-down left-right in Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4 with flexbox. I have an alphabetized list of items classed `col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xl-3` in a `container-fluid`.  The columns are responsive and the number of items is dynamic. Because of this, it is not possible to know the height of the container.

There can be either 1,2, 3, or 4 columns, and all the rows are exactly the same width by design.

DEMO:
https://codepen.io/troutr/pen/XKQYjV

Here is an image of how I want the order to work.
[image: Allow user to read top-down left to right]

For usability reasons, it would be nice if the items were ordered top-down, left to right. Is it possible to do this using CSS? I was thinking it may be possible using media queries and flexbox's `order` property.

Comment: Check the CSS property [`column-count`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_column-count.asp). But it's not compatible with older browsers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the CSS property [`column-count`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_column-count.asp). Also check for browser compatibility [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp).

```css
ul,
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
ul {
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  column-count: 3;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
</ul>
<hr>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I've used this with fairly good success. Seems to fail rather gracefully too.

Comment: @Pugazh's answer lead me in the correct direction. In fact, an even easier solution was to use `.list {columns: 4 20em; column-gap: 2em; }` for the `ul` element. Very very elegant solution. Now I have a fully responsive grid that reads top-down left right. Like a newspaper!